Python in Conda env is not execute
I try install Python v3.12 in a Conda env; however, when I typed Python in the terminal, it only opens that Python 2.7 that is shared on a HPC.
I try python -V. It shows /usr/bin/python2.7.
I checked whereis python, it shows both python2.7 and .conda/envs/testing/bin/python3.12

In conda.exe with you environment activated, try the full path to your desirable python executable, which you got from where python. For example:
(your_env) C:\Users\> D:\User\anaconda3\envs\your_env\python.exe

If you want the command to be short, then add the path to your python executable to system's PATH environment variable:
This PC -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables

Then System variables -> Edit -> New, and input the location, like {full_path}/envs/testing/bin/python3.12.
If you have multiple python executables, ensure that the path to the version you want to use by default is higher up in the list. Paths are searched in order, so the first match will be used.
Rename your python.exe to something like python312.exe, python310.exe, etc. Then you could call python by "python312" or "python310" etc. to run the specific versions.

yes possible, but everytime then I need to do the same typing, which is bad if I switch multiple conda env

@QXNg You would want to add the path to your python executable to the system's PATH. Check the answer.
